# Mongo SSL config with CA cert only works for rails console, not rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, compose-db, mongoid5

I am trying to configure a Rails 4.2.6 app to connect over SSL to a MongoDB cluster on compose.io. The app uses the mongo 2.4.1 and mongoid 5.1.5 gems. Compose.io MongoDB clusters use self-signed SSL certificates so I downloaded the CA certificate from compose.io and placed it in `lib/certs/mongo-ca-bundle.pem`.

My mongoid.yml file looks like this (redacted):

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://myuser:mypassword@some-host.dblayer.com:1111,some-other-host.dblayer.com:2222/mydb?ssl=true
      options:
        ssl_ca_cert: /path/to/myapp/lib/certs/mongo-ca-bundle.pem
```

The above configuration works perfectly when I run `rails console` and I can successfully run queries against collections in the compose.io database.

However, when I try to run `rails server` it crashes after 30 seconds with a "No server is available" error message:

```
[..]/mongo/server_selector/selectable.rb:115:in `select_server': No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x47167439625640 tag_sets=[] max_staleness=nil> using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015 (Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable)
[..]/mongo/cluster.rb:226:in `next_primary'
```

When I enable debug logging for mongoid it indicates that the problem is with the SSL handshake:

```
DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Server some-host.dblayer.com:1111 initializing.
DEBUG -- : MONGODB | SSL handshake failed. MongoDB may not be configured with SSL support.
```

I used to get the same error in the rails console until I added the `ssl_ca_cert` configuration. I did manage to get the server to connect by specifying `ssl_verify: false` but I don't consider that a valid workaround. How can I fix this? How come the console works but the server doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was missing a certificate in the CA-bundle causing the connection to fail. With the proper CA cert in the bundle, `rails server` can connect just fine.

The reason that `rails console` worked seems to be that it connects to the local mongodb instance even if I specify a different URL in `mongoid.yml`. This seems buggy to me, but I haven't investigated further.